# Converting results of Ebean query to JSON doesn't work

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

Right now I have

```
@Entity
public class Argument extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required @NotEmpty @Size(max = 140)
    public String summary;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Finder<Long, Argument> find = new Finder(Long.class, Argument.class);
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Relation extends Model
{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required @ManyToOne @NotNull @JsonManagedReference
    public Argument from;
    @ManyToOne @JsonManagedReference
    public Argument toArgument;
    @ManyToOne @JsonManagedReference
    public Relation toRelation;
    @Required @NotNull
    public Integer type;
    ...
}
```

Basically, a `Relation` links two arguments (or an argument and another relation) together. It's a one-direction relationship between the two classes. And yet I get

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion 
(StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: models.Argument["relations"]-> 
com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->models.Relation["from"]-> 
models.Argument["relations"]-> ... ->models.Argument["relations"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:611) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:142) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    ...
```

when I try to do

```
find.where().or(Expr.eq("from", argument), Expr.eq("toArgument", argument)).findList();
```

and later call `Json.toJson` on that result.

Adding `@JsonBackReference` to the fields that reference `Argument` solves the problem by leaving out those fields entirely, which is not what I want. Adding `@JsonManagedReference` keeps the problem unchanged because I don't see anywhere to add the `@JsonBackReference` -- it's a one-direction relationship, darn it!

Basically, all I want is a JSON array of relations involving a certain argument. The JSON objects representing the relations should only contain IDs -- something like `{id: 1, from: 4, toArgument: 3, type: 1}` would be exactly what I want.

**EDIT** I should add that views that previously worked fine with the `Argument` model are now encountering the same error when the request is in JSON -- despite working *solely* with Arguments! Why would something in a completely different class affect Argument when I'm not even changing Argument at all?

Answer (score 5):

Solved it finally with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13785612/257583) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9108623/257583) answer. I had to add

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "from") @JsonBackReference
public List<Relation> fromThis;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "toArgument") @JsonBackReference
public List<Relation> toThis;
```

to `Argument`.

Don't totally understand why, and now I get the entire Argument object embedded in the JSON -- instead of only the ID, which was what I wanted. Oh well, I guess.